# Hyper-V VM very slow after live migrating to very similar hardware.

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2

I live migrated Windows 2012 R2 Vose from Windows 2012 R2 server to another Windows 2012 R2 server running hyper-v. After the migrate this migrated Vose is running very poorly and uses lot of virtual CPUs but it does not eat much physical CPUs on that Hyper-V host. (even when I enabled 11 virtual cores out of 12). Also its only thing which is running on the server, server is in server core mode.

Old server is HP Gen9 Rack type server, new server is HP Gen9 Tower type server. Both have same CPU (Inter(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz) 6 cores +hyperthreading. Both have same type of Hard Drives too and 16Gig ram.

On old server remote desktop connection works flawlessly and has pretty much no lag, on this new server its very laggy with gigabit connection.

I do not have much experience on hyper-v, I wonder if there there is way to reset CPU based stuff on VM or recreate VM with same VM harddisk drive? (tried this, but was not able to create boot sector).

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the guest OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing stuff out and googling found that it was network issue and was happening because of VQM and Broadcom Network Adapters. 
This post helped me solve it: 
http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2k7jn5/after_2_years_i_have_finally_solved_my_slow/

Had to enable VQM everywhere and create registery value BelowTenGigVqmEnabled with value of 1 in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VMSMP\Parameters.